# How do I create a wordpress navigation menu which changes the background image on hover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, menu

I saw this website and I like the navigation  of the website 
ref: http://www.visitvirginiabeach.com 
When you hover the mouse over each menu the big picture will change.

I have tried integrate the jQuery with the class but it didn't work at all.

```
$(".nav-item1").hover(function){
$(".bg-nav").css('background','url('images/bg2.jpg')');
}
```

Is there any plugin or some advanced jQuery coding that can make this happen?

Any answer is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: `function){` should be `function(){` and the quotes in the `url` should be double quotes `"images/bg2.jpg"`

Comment: you have a syntax error on each line of code....use browser console to check for errors

Answer (score 0):

```
body {
font-family: verdana,arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
}
#nav,#nav ul{
line-height: 50px;
    list-style-position: outside;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
}
a{
background-color: #B7AF0E;
    border: 1px solid #B7AF0E;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    display: block;
    padding: 0 5px 0 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover{
background-color:#F8EBA5;
color:#77885B;
}
#nav li{    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
#nav ul {
position:absolute;
display:none;

}
#nav ul li a {
    width: 140px;
    float: left;
    height: auto;
}
#nav ul ul{
top:auto;
}
#nav li ul ul {
left:6em;
margin:0px 0 0 35px;
}
#nav li:hover ul ul, #nav li:hover ul ul ul, #nav li:hover ul ul ul ul{
display:none;
}

#nav li:hover ul, #nav li li:hover ul, #nav li li li:hover ul, #nav li li li li:hover ul{
display:block;
}
</style>
<script>
function mainmenu(){
$(" #nav ul ").css({display: "none"}); // Opera Fix
$(" #nav li").hover(function(){
        $(this).find('ul:first').css({visibility: "visible",display: "none"}).show();
        },function(){
        $(this).find('ul:first').css({visibility: "hidden"});
        });
}



 $(document).ready(function(){                  
    mainmenu();
});
</script>`<body>

<ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Testimonials</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Gallery</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Gallery 1</a>
                <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Gallery 1.1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Gallery 1.2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Gallery 2</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Gallery 2.2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Gallery 2.2</a></li>
                </ul>   
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Gallery 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">PHP</a>
                <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Wordpress</li>
                <li><a href="#">Magento</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">ASP.NET</a>
                <ul>    
                    <li><a href="#">Project 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">project 2</a></li>
                </ul>       
            </li>

        </ul>   
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
</body>`
```